# CORS HTTP redirects (30x) not followed by Android / iOS WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview, xmlhttprequest, cors

Scenario:

- a WebView (Android 4.x) loads a page via http (not file://)
- the page contains a xhr request (native or jQuery, same result) to a resource on *another domain*
- the resource redirects to another resource (some domain or not, same result) via 307 (or any other 30x, same result)
- I get the infamous "error", with any other information

Note that:

- if it's not a redirection, the request is fullfilled
- if all the resources are on the same server, the request is fullfilled
- CORS headers are set both for the resource which redirects and the final one
- on Chrome or Firefox everything works perfectly
- I am in control of everything (Android App, server and web pages)
- "manual" redirection works, the WebView will follow the 307 if I click on a A element
- The final URL is not hit by the WebView, which (apparently) means that it detects something wrong on the first response
- I do not use the BASE element

JS code is basically this one

`var url = "http://xxxxxx/zot";
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.onerror = function() {
      // I received the error
    };
    oReq.onload = function(e) {
      // Not reached
    };
    oReq.open("GET", url, true);
    oReq.send();`

Headers spit by the first request:

```
HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: connection,host,accept-language,accept-encoding,accept-charset,user-agent,origin,cache-control,pragma,referer,origin,X-Requested-With,x-requested-with,accept-charset,x-wap-profile,x-getzip, Access-Control-Allow-Origin,X-HTTP-Method-Override,Content-Type,Authorization,Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Location: http://10.90.7.10:3030/r/vast
Date: Fri, 11 Apr 2014 09:40:01 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

(Trying removing all of them, part of them, etc etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem. Unfortunately WebViews tend to send custom headers within each requests, and that fact will trigger the *CORS with preflight* kind of request. But I have a redirection, which for preflight requests are explicitely forbidden by the standard (http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0, section 3)

> If the response has an HTTP status code that is not in the 2xx range [then] Apply the network error steps.

For example, my XPeria T is sending `x-wap-profile` and `x-getzip` but also the `x-requested-with`.

Comment: You've quoted the wrong section of the spec.  You've linked to the preflighting section, but quoted from the simple CORS request section.  Furthermore, you've mis-quoted that section as well.  For simple CORS requests, redirection is allowed.  If a 301-308 is returned, the [redirection steps](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#redirect-steps) are followed.  If a non 2xx is received in a response to a preflight, THEN the request is considered a failure.  The relevant portion of the spec is: "If the response has an HTTP status code that is not in the 2xx range... Apply the network error steps."

Comment: You're right. I found the problem but I've gone too quickly through the spec.